# mod_rewrite rule to allow a single URL to be served without SSL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hi currently I have a rewrite rule that forces all requests under SSL. I want to whitelist a single URL prefix to ignore this rule, so only that URL can be served under both protocols.

Original rule:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

My attempt at an updated rule:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/preview/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Any URL that starts with /preview/blah/blah should be ignored from the redirect.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

[ edit ]

Changing the rules as outlined below, it doesn't seem to process the second rule? Here's my full .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/preview/
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

When I go to /preview/blah it changes the URL to https://domain.com/index.php?/preview/blah

[ edit2 ]

Darn browser cache! It works :)

Comment: Saw your edit. Please always post _all_ current rewrite rules. They're very sensitive to order. Hold on and I'll edit below.

Comment: If I visit under HTTPS, the URL is this:

https://domain.com/preview/Z5bbbbbbbc/u

If you visit NOT under SSL, it should be the same w/o the s:

http://domain.com/preview/Z5bbbbbbbc/u

Comment: So the `/preview` should be sheltered both from HTTPS and from `index.php?/$1`?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by sheltered? The URL should be the same in both cases, so if /preview ignore the SSL redirect rule and use the last rule to format the URL for CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're merely failing to *negate* `!` the `RewriteCond`.  That should be all you need (though you can simplify it by removing the `()` capture group and `$` anchor).

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
# Negate the condition with !, and the (.*)$ isn't needed.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/preview/
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I would probably simplify the `RewriteRule` to match only `^` as well, since `.*` without a `()` capture group matches "anything or nothing" and then just throws it away. As in:

```
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

My other recommendation would be instead of matching for port 80, to cover the possible situation where you're serving on a port other than 80 (such as in development), match for `%{HTTPS} !on`. So in total:

```
# Instead of 
# RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
# Your first condition can be
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/preview/
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks! Updated my post, do you know why the second rule isn't working when your new rule does trigger?